# Join columns from tables and merge rows with same id

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a SQL query and I've completely lost myself in the joins. Hopefully you will be able to assist :)

My problem is that the rows from the separate tables are not merged into a single row where they all have the same id. Joins have been confusing to me for a long time so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following tables:

```
Students
id

StudentCredits
sum_credits

StudentMandatoryCredits
branch_credits
program_credits
```

I'm trying to create a query that will give me rows like this:

```
id         - sum_credits - branch_credits - program_credits
another_id - sum_credits - branch_credits - program_credits
a_third_id - sum_credits - branch_credits - program_credits
```

This is the best I can come up with though:

```
id - sum_credits - branch_credits -     [empty]
id - sum_credits -     [empty]    - program_credits
```

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT S.id, SC.sum_credits, SMC.branch_credits, SMC.program_credits
FROM Students S
LEFT JOIN StudentCredits SC ON S.id = SC.id
LEFT JOIN StudentMandatoryCredits SMC ON S.id = SMC.id
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
SELECT S.id, SUM(SC.sum_credits), SUM(SMC.branch_credits), SUM(SMC.program_credits)
FROM Students S
LEFT JOIN StudentCredits SC ON S.id = SC.id
LEFT JOIN StudentMandatoryCredits SMC ON S.id = SMC.id
GROUP BY S.id
ORDER BY S.id
```

Comment: Very nice! I was trying to use GROUP BY S.id but got errors on the other attributes. Never thought of using SUM() on them! THANKS! (and group by goes before ordering, at least in the dbms I'm using).